# How do I send an arbitary message to an Ethereum address?

Tags: transactions, dapps, whisper

How can I send a message to another Ethereum address? And how would that user receiving know that its a message? Is there an Ethereum wallet that will show that I sent a message to that address? And what is the max size I can send?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So it is only possible to send HEX data in the `data` field. This will not be a standard transaction but will require you to use geth, [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com/account) advanced settings on the send page, or another client that allows you to access and edit the `data` field.

1. Google and visit an [ascii->hex site](http://www.asciitohex.com/) and type your message.
2. Copy the hexadecimal output, and remove all the spaces in that hexadecimal output. Then paste it into the `data` field.
3. On etherscan, you can click the "convert to ascii" at the bottom of any TX that has data. Not all data is ascii data though, so it will be gibberish sometimes.
4. I sent a demo [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x904f8e3af19f1fdbbe7a0e534b6a8f080ff6b2ad79c7a874cee22b53ee70f717). Under "payload", you can see the HEX data on the left and the ASCII on the right.

---

As euro10 pointed out in the comments (but it's a bit hard to read), you can actually use built-in ascii -> hex if you are using geth:

`eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0],to:eth.accounts[1],value:web3.toWei(1‌​00,'finney'),data:web3.toHex('John Doe sent you a message')})`

Comment: you can use the built-in ascii to hex should you use geth : `eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0],to:eth.accounts[1],value:web3.toWei(100,'finney'),data:web3.toHex('John Doe sent you a message')})` you can see here https://etherchain.org/tx/0xeb764262be2f3f2125bbbee854b0a089d01eacb9f5a458d34e69f2b6160e600a

Comment: It's much easier than this. In the Mist browser, you can just copy and paste your hex string there. It recalculates gas, etc. Rapid Tables is a good site for converting text to hex. This is basically what I did here: https://medium.com/@tjayrush/knowing-the-future-and-proving-you-know-it-3add7a69d54c#.ma7ac4fux

Comment: Must I use ASCII? UTF-8?

Comment: How can I receive message? Any sample js code?

Comment: @tayvano, Can you please provide sample code to read the message?

Comment: You can read the message by converting hex back to ascii. Scroll down this page and enter the HEX under "hexadecimal" and remove the prefixing 0x (if it is there): http://www.asciitohex.com/. Here's a JS tutorial: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-string-exercise-27.php

Comment: or use site like ama.fans.

Answer (score 9):

By sending a message, I assume you mean you want to send some form of a text based message to another user...

- You can send a message as part of the data field in a transaction.
- For the user to know you actually sent them a message, you could use the web3.js api to listen and extract messages from a transaction. You'd then have to decode it to ascii to make it human readable.
- I'm not aware of a wallet that will show you sent a specific message to an address, but a wallet such as Mist will show you sent a transaction to a given address
- I believe there is a max size for transaction (which would include your message). I'm not positive, but I think it's currently around 80kb...?

And alternative to the approach above is to use a contract to post an event to the blockchain. A client can then listen for these specific events again using the web3.js api.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you would do it with the web3 api.

```
const Utils = require('web3-utils');
let txTransfer = {};
txTransfer.from = from.address;
txTransfer.to = to.address;
txTransfer.gas = GasLimit;
txTransfer.value = amount;
txTransfer.data = Utils.toHex('free text data');
web3.eth.sendTransaction(txTransfer);
```

I have a working example on the blockchain at this transaction [0x99f537b788c1e0c9513735c644921ffa423f8bd20ce45165403e8f12942aaca8](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x99f537b788c1e0c9513735c644921ffa423f8bd20ce45165403e8f12942aaca8). The ascii data in the transaction was the same JavaScript used to send the transaction.

Answer (score 4):

web3js v1.x.x

```js
const txParams = {
  nonce: nonce,
  gasPrice: gasPrice,
  gasLimit: gasLimit,
  to: to,
  value: value,
  data : web3.utils.toHex('rockstar blockchain developer'),
  // EIP 155 chainId - mainnet: 1, ropsten: 3
  chainId: 4
}

const tx = new ethereumTx(txParams);

tx.sign(privateKey);
const serializedTx = '0x'+tx.serialize().toString('hex')

console.log("serializedTx" ,serializedTx );
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx);
```

Tx hash of successful example on rinkeBy test net [0xbc5ef9dc8da24c90d5910d93419f9746f3fe318cb2f2b5e7c873e64264bfcf53](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xbc5ef9dc8da24c90d5910d93419f9746f3fe318cb2f2b5e7c873e64264bfcf53)

Comment: Honest question, why use `sendSignedTransaction` instead of just `sendTransaction`? What benefits does the signed one have?

Comment: It's more flexible. There are some benefits to signing with a private key not held by web3. For example you could load the private key from a brainwallet or generated in  an offline way (through dice rolls)

Answer (score 0):

You use `Whisper` (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper)

---

### Solution using `Web3.py`:

I have followed following [ssh-mode code](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/tests/core/shh-module/test_shh_filter.py).

---

`receiver.py` that runs on node-1:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
from web3.shh import Shh
Shh.attach(web3, "shh")

import time, sys;

from hexbytes import (
    HexBytes,
)

kId = web3.shh.newKeyPair()
receiver_pub = web3.shh.getPublicKey(kId)
print('receiverPubK: ' + receiver_pub);

topic = '0x07678231'

shh_filter = web3.shh.newMessageFilter({
    'privateKeyID': kId,
    'topics': [topic]
})

input("Press Enter to continue...");

received_messages = [];
received_messages = shh_filter.get_new_entries()
print(len(received_messages)) # Returns '0'
print(web3.shh.info.memory)  # Returns '0'
```

Output:

```
receiverPubK: 0x04226d96bf9857ac0ba429c1e8b480a2811ce47cb526dbd3829d7586e5cae740198ba291f3eca0f279f82db8a136be90ea9ec629ed6cd1d45cc7f873159811757d
Press Enter to continue...
```

---

After `Node_1`'s messages are sent; I have copied printed `receiverPublicKey` into `receiver_pub` variable on the following code. I run following code on `Node 2`. `Node 2` sends a message to the network. Later I press enter on the `Node_1` and `Node_1` prints the message

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
from web3.shh import Shh
Shh.attach(web3, "shh")

import time, sys;

from hexbytes import (
    HexBytes,
)

receiver_pub='0x04226d96bf9857ac0ba429c1e8b480a2811ce47cb526dbd3829d7586e5cae740198ba291f3eca0f279f82db8a136be90ea9ec629ed6cd1'; # obtained from node_1 and assigned here.

topic = '0x07678231'
payloads = [web3.toHex(text="test message :)"), web3.toHex(text="2nd test message")]

web3.shh.post({
        'powTarget': 2.5,
        'powTime': 2,
        'ttl': 60,
        'payload': payloads[0],
        'topic': topic,
        'pubKey': receiver_pub
})
```