# I sent tokens to the wrong Ethereum token address from my Trust Wallet?

Tags: metamask, wallets, addresses

I intended to send tokens to my Metamask address, but made an error on the token address which turned out to be a legitimate address, so the transaction was successful but it was not my intended address. My tokens are now in someone else wallet. I was told by BScan to try reaching out to the person via EOA. I have no idea what to do. Some help here please.

Answer (score 1):

If you send tokens to someone, then want them back, you can only request that person to send you back. Otherwise, an efficient way does not exist (you could bribe validators to reorg the tx out, but that will be very costly and hence not efficient).

What is the destination address?

- Is it a person you know? => need to communicate over social media.
- Is it a person you don't know? => need to communicate over onchain message.
- Is it a smart contract? => that's bad luck :(
- Is it some exchange address? => likely you'll get funds back by creating a support ticket.

> I was told by BScan to try reaching out to the person via EOA. I have no idea what to do. Some help here please.

For communicating with persons you don't know, this is a classic way to send an on-chain public message to an address, which is viewable by anyone who is looking at the address's page on the explorer. Example message: "hey, it would be great if you could partially return my funds, thank you in advance!". If it happens that the person who owns the private key for the address sees this message, they might consider to act on it or simply ignore the message.

Some tutorials to do this:

- https://dame.mirror.xyz/5xbwbVzWcO8vQkEIGlMaUjXNM6UNM8labiN-5QkVCHM
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYteFcqLKek
- [How do I send an arbitary message to an Ethereum address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-send-an-arbitary-message-to-an-ethereum-address)

Also Good luck! I know this is very frustrating, happens to the best of us.